# Program output (Basic operators for c++). Order of operations?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

```
// H2.cpp : Tihs program runs different mathmatical operations on numbers given by the user

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Enter a number for a: "; //Prompts the user for a and b inputs
    cin >> a;

    int b;
    cout << "Enter a number for b: ";
    cin >> b;

    cout << "A is " << a << "\tB is " << b << endl;
    cout <<"Sum of a and b is equal to " << a << " + " << b << " and the result is " << (a + b) << endl; //Performs addition operator and gives output
    cout <<"Product of a and b is equal to " << a << " * " << b << " and the result is " << (a * b) << endl;
    cout <<"a > b is " << a << " > " << b << " and the result is " << (a > b) << endl;
    cout <<"a < b is " << a << " > " << b << " and the result is " << (a < b) << endl;
    cout <<"a == b is " << a << " == " << b << " and the result is " << (a == b) << endl; //Performs boolean operator and outputs result
    cout <<"a >= b is " << a << " >= " << b << " and the result is " << (a >= b) << endl;
    cout <<"a <= b is " << a << " <= " << b << " and the result is " << (a <= b) << endl;
    cout <<"a != b is " << a << " != " << b << " and the result is " << (a != b) << endl;
    cout <<"a -= b is " << a << " -= " << b << " and the result is a = " << (a -= b) << endl; //Performs - operator on a - b and makes a equal to the new result
    cout <<"a /= b is " << a << " /= " << b << " and the result is a = " << (a /= b) << endl;
    cout <<"a %= b is " << a << " %= " << b << " and the result is a = " << (a %= b) << endl; //Performs % operator on a % b and makes a equal to the new result. Ripple effect created from previous 2 lines as the value of a changes each time.

return 0;
```

The output I'm concerned with is here:

```
a -= b is -4198672 -= 4198672 and the result is a = -4198672
a /= b is -1 /= 4198672 and the result is a = -1
a %= b is -1 %= 4198672 and the result is a = -1
```

It seems like the value for a being displayed is the value of a after the line of code is executed. I'm sure that has something to do with the order of operations, but I'm not sure how to get around that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not really about order-of-operations, but more about [`Order of Evaluation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)

Answer (score 1):

The order in which arguments to operators or functions are evaluated is undefined in C++. If the evaluation of the different arguments have side effects, these can happen whenever the compiler sees fit and if there multiple modifications to the same object the result is undefined behavior. If you want to force a specific evaluation order, you'd need to break your expression down into multiple separate expression as these are evaluated in order or you could inject operators which create a sequence point. However, the operators creating a sequence point don't play nicely with chaining output operators. The list of operators forcing the first argument to be evaluate before the other arguments are:

- the , operator
- the logical && and || operators
- the conditional operator ?:

Of course, if you overload any of these operators, they stop introducing a sequence point as they become normal function calls.

Comment: It is a bit more complicated, see the `<<` operator for `std::ostream`-s; in `std::cout << 1 << "a" << std::endl` the order *is* well defined...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The order in which the _operators are called_ is, indeed, defined! I didn't claim that it would not be defined. However, the order in which the _arguments_ (`std::cout`, `1`, `"a"`, and `std::endl`) are evaluate is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

All the operators you have listed are comparison operators which return value true or false.

Except: -=, /= and %= operators

a-=b is actually a=a-b.

Just check if you are sure that you wanted this in first place?

BTW:  if(a=b) is also returns true since it is always success but I do not think we do this intentionally.